# Sum up the options selected by a user with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a personality quiz and I want to sum up the options selected by the user. What I have currently is that the programs count the number of values selected in this line and displays it `$this->db->where('options', 2);`, here it is 2. Rather than it to count I want it to add instead. Below are my model and controller.

Model

```
<?php
class testing_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_q()
    {
        return $this->db->get('questions')->result();
    } 
    public function get_o($q_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('q_id', $q_id);
        return $this->db->get('options')->result();
    }
    public function result($q_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('q_id', $q_id);
        $this->db->where('options', 2);
        return $this->db->get('options')->row()->o_id;
    } 
}
```

Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class testing_con extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model("testing_model");
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['question'] = $this->testing_model->get_q();
        $this->load->view('testing_view', $data);
    }
    public function submit()
    {
        $score = 0;
        foreach($_POST['quetionId'] as $q_id) {
            if($this->testing_model->result($q_id) == $_POST['questions_' .$q_id]){
                $score++;
            }
        }
        
        $data['score'] = $score;
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
    }
}
```